# how to stop puppeteer-recorder recording

Tags: puppeteer

im using `puppeteer-recorder` to record a video from browser activity

this package
https://www.npmjs.com/package/puppeteer-recorder

here is my code

```
async function check_login()
{

    try {



        const page = await global_browser.newPage();
        await page.setViewport({width: 1000, height: 1100});

        record({
            browser: global_browser, // Optional: a puppeteer Browser instance,
            page: page, // Optional: a puppeteer Page instance,
            output: path + 'output.webm',
            fps: 60,
            frames: 60 * 5, // 5 seconds at 60 fps
            prepare: function () {}, // <-- add this line
            render: function () {} // <-- add this line

        });

        await page.goto('http://localhost/home_robot/mock.php', {timeout: 60000})
            .catch(function (error) {
                throw new Error('TimeoutBrows');
            });


        await page.close();



    }
    catch (e) {
        console.log(' LOGIN ERROR ---------------------');
        console.log(e);
    }
}
```

it works fine but i dont know how to stop recording and so when i get to the end of function i get this error

```
(node:10000) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: Protocol error (Emulation.setDefaultBackgroundColorOverride): Target closed.
    at Promise (C:\wamp64\www\home_robot\node_modules\puppeteer\lib\Connection.js:202:56)
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
    at CDPSession.send (C:\wamp64\www\home_robot\node_modules\puppeteer\lib\Connection.js:201:12)
    at Page._screenshotTask (C:\wamp64\www\home_robot\node_modules\puppeteer\lib\Page.js:806:26)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:68:7)
(node:10000) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (
rejection id: 1)
(node:10000) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
```

and i dont get a video file , i assume its because i close the page without stopping the record

unfortunately there's no documentation and the author doesn't answer the questions

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no way or need to stop recording with this module, look closely at the `frames` option of the `record` method:

> ```
> frames: 60 * 5, // 5 seconds at 60 fps
> ```

After getting 300 frames it will stop by itself.

However for it to work a very important requirement must be met and documentation won't mention it, but you can see it in the source of the module: it uses `ffmpeg` to make video from screenshots AND that must be in PATH. If not you should provide ffmpeg binary location in options:

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');
const { record } = require('puppeteer-recorder');

puppeteer.launch({headless : false}).then(async browser => {
    const page = await browser.newPage();

    await page.goto('https://codepen.io/hexagoncircle/full/joqYEj', {waitUntil : 'networkidle2'});

    await record({
        ffmpeg: "c:\\ffmpeg\\bin\\ffmpeg.exe" // <-- provide full path to ffmpeg binary
        browser: browser, // Optional: a puppeteer Browser instance,
        page: page, // Optional: a puppeteer Page instance,
        output: 'output.webm',
        fps: 24,
        frames: 24, // desired seconds of recording multiplied by fps
        prepare: function (browser, page) { /* you could click on a button */ },
        render: function (browser, page, frame) { /* executed before each capture */ }
    });    

    await browser.close();
});
```

Result:

[image: result of recording]

Comment: Is it possible to record with the same frame rate as the page? This seems to be super high speed compared to the actual page

Comment: Have you experimented with `fps` parameter?

Comment: I did but no luck

Comment: The problem is that it does not adhere to the frame rate of the page. You can see in your response video that the speed is much higher that the actual page. For 24fps you would expect somewhat a normal video

Comment: I think those are just 24 screenshots that were fed into ffmpeg. Over what timespan were they taken? Certainly not at 1/24s each, much slower. Probably that explains the speed. Try to go with 15, 10 fps, try lowering the resolution.